# Can contract generated with pact-jvm be verified by pact-net or pact-ruby?

Tags: pact

Using pact-jvm-consumer-junit body can have

```
 DslPart etaResults = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .integerType("x",1)
                .asBody();
```

That result in contract file:

```
"$.body.x": {
   "match": "integer"
}
```

Using pact-net or pact-provider-verifier to verify the contract the following message is shown:
WARN: Ignoring unsupported matching rules {"match"=>"integer"} for path $['body']['x']

Setting output to PactSpecVersion.V2 using PactProviderRule does not help, still same error.

Is the current pact-provider-verifier supposed to be able to read contract that contains 
 "match": "integer".
What version of pact specification is pact-provider-verifier really expecting?

Is it a bugg that pact-jvm set to PactSpecVersion.V2 supposed to output "match": "integer" or should it be "match": "type"?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like it's being serialised as `v3` instead of `v2`, as you say, `integer` is not a valid type for `v2`.

If you could provide a gist of your code (or better, a working example) we can probably get to the bottom of it.

In short, however, v2 serialised pacts should be compatible with other languages that support v2.

Comment: See working example here: https://github.com/mattiasmgn/randomint